# Merge multiple DataFrame columns into one

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to transform a DataFrame with a dynamic number of `a_P` columns looking like this

```
             a1_P       a2_P     weight  
0        33297.81   17407.93   14733.23  
1        58895.18   43013.57   86954.04
```

into a new DataFrame, looking like this (sorted by P)

```
                P     weight  
0        17407.93   14733.23
1        33297.81   14733.23  
2        43013.57   86954.04
3        58895.18   86954.04
```

So what I'm trying so far is

```
names = ["a1", "a2"]
p = pd.DataFrame(columns=["P", "weight"])
for i in range(0, len(names)):
  p += df[["{}_P".format(names[i]), "weight"]]
```

and to sort it afterwards but this does not work because columnnames are not identical I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The pandas.melt function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) does something like what you want:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['weight'], value_vars=['a1_P', 'a2_P'], value_name='P')
     weight variable         P
0  14733.23     a1_P  33297.81
1  86954.04     a1_P  58895.18
2  14733.23     a2_P  17407.93
3  86954.04     a2_P  43013.57
```

And of course, soring by `P` is easily done by appending a `.sort('P')` to the end of the melt statement.

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['weight'], value_vars=['a1_P', 'a2_P'], value_name='P').sort('P')
     weight variable         P
2  14733.23     a2_P  17407.93
0  14733.23     a1_P  33297.81
3  86954.04     a2_P  43013.57
1  86954.04     a1_P  58895.18
```

And if you want to be super dynamic, maybe generating the `value_vars` in this fancy way:

```
n_values = 2
value_vars = ["a{}_P".format(i+1) for i in range(0, n_values)]
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['weight'], value_vars=value_vars, value_name='P').sort('P')
```

To get the index to be `[0, 1, 2, 3 ...]`, just use `.reset_index(drop=True)` either as a chained event, or like this:

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['weight'], value_vars=value_vars, value_name='P')
df.sort(inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

I personally prefer inplace operations, because they are much much more memory efficient.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what `melt` is designed for. In this particular example. you don't even need to specify `value_vars`. Nor does `id_vars` have to be a list. This is enough: `pd.melt(df, id_vars='weight')`

Comment: @LondonRob Good point! Though "Explicit is better than implicit". I also assumed the example in the question to be simplified. There may be a tonnes of other unwanted columns in there.

Comment: This very short and works well, thanks for that! And yes, there are a lot of other columns in there. For completion: there a line such like df = df.reset_index(drop=True) missing to get the final result I wanted.

Comment: @Peter I added some more code for the `.reset_index()`

Comment: Thanks for the advice about memory efficiency, didnt think about it.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution using Pandas `concat` (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html):

```
import pandas as pd                                                                           

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a1_P': [123.123, 342.123],
                             'a2_P': [232.12, 32.23],
                             'weight': [12312.23, 16232.3]})                        

cols = [x for x in df.columns if '_P' in x]                                         

new = pd.concat([df[col] for col in cols])                                          
oldidx = new.index                                                                  
weights = df.loc[new.index, 'weight'].tolist()                                      

new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'P': new,                                          
                                 'weight': weights})                                
new_df.sort(columns='P', inplace=True)                                           
new_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)   

print(new_df)

         P    weight                                                                          
0   32.230  16232.30
1  123.123  12312.23
2  232.120  12312.23
3  342.123  16232.30
```

There is room for performance optimizations, but it should faster than a solution with explicit loops.